# jquery ui - how to connect / drag & drop / sortable lists between tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to put together a page to facilitate tabs and ordering of items within 3 columns in aforementioned tabs.

I can now move items between tabs but not between the columns within the tabs.

this is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rmprH/5/

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Update your droppable call to

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6, #sortable7").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmprH/116/)